# Issue with my Gradle script: Could not find property 'groovy' on source set

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I am having trouble with my Gradle build script since I added a custom end2endTest task.

Here is the section of the build script corresponding to one of my projects:

```
project("bignibou-server") {
    description = "Bignibou Server"

    configurations { querydslapt }

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

    dependencies {
        compile project(":bignibou-client")

        //Spring bootbignibou-server
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
        ...


        // Testing
        testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
        testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:${springSecurityVersion}")
        testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}")
        testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:${hamcrestVersion}")
        testCompile("org.easytesting:fest-assert:${festVersion}")
        ...
    }

    springBoot { mainClassName = "com.bignibou.Application" }


    sourceSets {
        generated {
            java { srcDirs = [ 'build/generated-sources/java'
                ] } }

        main { java { srcDir 'build/generated-sources/java' } }

        integrationTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/it/java']
            resources.srcDir file('src/it/resources')
            compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
        }

        end2endTest {
            java.srcDirs = []
            groovy.srcDirs = ['src/end2end/groovy']
            compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime + sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
        }
    }

    task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
        description "Generates the QueryDSL query types"
        source = sourceSets.main.java
        classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
        options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor",
            "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
        ]
        destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
    }

    task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        description "Run the integration tests."
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
        reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/integration")
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/integration")
    }

    task end2endTest(type: Test) {
        description "Run the end2end tests."
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.end2endTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.end2endTest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.integrationTest.compileClasspath
        reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/end2end")
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/end2end")
    }


    compileJava {
        dependsOn generateQueryDSL
        source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir
    }

    compileGeneratedJava {
        dependsOn generateQueryDSL
        options.warnings = false
        classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }

    compileGroovy {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    end2endTest {
        doFirst {
            systemProperties['geb.build.reportsDir'] = 'build/geb-reports'
            systemProperties['geb.build.baseUrl'] = 'http://localhost:8080/'
        }
    }

    check.dependsOn integrationTest
    integrationTest.shouldRunAfter test
    end2endTest.shouldRunAfter integrationTest

    clean {
        delete sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs
    }
}
```

when I run a  `gradle clean end2endTest`

I get the following:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'bignibou'.
> Could not find property 'groovy' on source set 'end end test'.
```

I am not sure why the groovy plugin doesn't find the groovy property..

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: Here is the complete file: [gist here](https://gist.github.com/balteo/ad60db682ae8e87f2c69)

**edit 2**: This is the failing line:

```
groovy.srcDirs = ['src/end2end/groovy']
```

**edit 3**: If I comment out the last part of the `compileClasspath` variable (in end2end source set) as follows:

```
compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime //+ sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
```

Then the gradle build goes further and I get compile errors.

What I tried to achieve by adding the `sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir` to the compile classpath was for the end2end tests to be able to use the compiled classes from the integration test task.

So how can I add the resulting .class files from the integration test task to be used to compile the end2end test task?

Comment: Which line is failing?

Comment: I have edited my post as required

Comment: Very strange. I recommend to strip down the build script until you find what's causing the problem. Perhaps try not to apply `spring-boot` for a moment. Also try to set `groovy.srcDirs` for a different source set (e.g. `main`). Also try with a recent Gradle version.

Comment: Does the order in which plugins are applied matter?

Comment: Not if they are implemented correctly (except that you need to apply the `groovy` plugin before you can set `groovy.srcDirs`).

Comment: Yet another thing to try is `groovy { srcDirs = ... }` instead of `groovy.srcDirs = ...`.

Comment: I have tried  `groovy { srcDirs = ... }` to no avail.

Comment: I have tried commenting the boot plugin too. It does not work either.

Comment: Best chance is to strip down until the problem disappears. I can't see anything wrong with the build script. Also try with a different Gradle version.

Comment: I am going to try that and post here accordingly then. Bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried syntax ?:

```
groovy { srcDirs = ['src/end2end/groovy'] }
```

But look what you have here :

> sourceSets {
>           generated {
>               java { srcDirs = [ 'build/generated-sources/java'
>                   ] } }

in sourceSets you have only java closure, here you have to specify if compile sources with java or with groovy. The issue is probably that you have to add groovy to sourceSet for example:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java { srcDirs = [] }    // no source dirs for the java compiler
    groovy { srcDirs = ['src/end2end/groovy'] }  // compile everything in src/ with groovy
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    resources { srcDirs = ['src/resources']}
  }
```